# pending - Waiting for next available executor in Hudson

Tags: build, hudson, executor

In hudson, am getting "**pending - Waiting for next available executor**" while building my job.Its showing **Build Executor status as "Dead(!)"**

Can anyone tell how to overcome this issue?
how to make hudson dead executor alive?